# Change matrix dimensions and fill it by Row

Tags: r, matrix

**In R,** I was wondering how I can restructure the following Matrix:

## From:

```
m = matrix( c("p.b1.1", "p.b1.2", "p.b1.3", "p.b1.4", "p.b2.1", "p.b2.2", "p.b2.3", 
              "p.b2.4", "p.b3.1", "p.b3.2", "p.b3.3", "p.b3.4", "p.b4.1", "p.b4.2", 
              "p.b4.3", "p.b4.4", "p.b5.1", "p.b5.2", "p.b5.3", "p.b5.4", "p.b6.1", 
              "p.b6.2", "p.b6.3", "p.b6.4", "p.b7.1", "p.b7.2", "p.b7.3", "p.b7.4"))
```

## To:

```
       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]    
[1,] "p.b1.1" "p.b1.2" "p.b1.3" "p.b1.4"
[2,] "p.b2.1" "p.b2.2" "p.b2.3" "p.b2.4"
[3,] "p.b3.1" "p.b3.2" "p.b3.3" "p.b3.4"
[4,] "p.b4.1" "p.b4.2" "p.b4.3" "p.b4.4"
[5,] "p.b5.1" "p.b5.2" "p.b5.3" "p.b5.4"
[6,] "p.b6.1" "p.b6.2" "p.b6.3" "p.b6.4"
[7,] "p.b7.1" "p.b7.2" "p.b7.3" "p.b7.4"`
```

Comment: To the down-voter, when down-voting a question like this consider that an OP with small programming knowledge is probably trying to learn from YOU, and after some desperation has posted her/his simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the following should do the trick:

```
matrix(m, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]    
#[1,] "p.b1.1" "p.b1.2" "p.b1.3" "p.b1.4"
#[2,] "p.b2.1" "p.b2.2" "p.b2.3" "p.b2.4"
#[3,] "p.b3.1" "p.b3.2" "p.b3.3" "p.b3.4"
#[4,] "p.b4.1" "p.b4.2" "p.b4.3" "p.b4.4"
#[5,] "p.b5.1" "p.b5.2" "p.b5.3" "p.b5.4"
#[6,] "p.b6.1" "p.b6.2" "p.b6.3" "p.b6.4"
#[7,] "p.b7.1" "p.b7.2" "p.b7.3" "p.b7.4"
```

And ~1 microsecond (1 millionth of a second) for running the above 1000 times should be efficient enough.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(matrix(m, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE), times = 1000)
Unit: nanoseconds
                              expr min  lq    mean median   uq  max neval
 matrix(m, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE) 511 767 967.773    767 1023 7410  1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `m` is already a matrix, its enough to re-set the `dim` and transpose it:

```
dim(m) <- c(4,7)
t(m)

     # [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]    
# [1,] "p.b1.1" "p.b1.2" "p.b1.3" "p.b1.4"
# [2,] "p.b2.1" "p.b2.2" "p.b2.3" "p.b2.4"
# [3,] "p.b3.1" "p.b3.2" "p.b3.3" "p.b3.4"
# [4,] "p.b4.1" "p.b4.2" "p.b4.3" "p.b4.4"
# [5,] "p.b5.1" "p.b5.2" "p.b5.3" "p.b5.4"
# [6,] "p.b6.1" "p.b6.2" "p.b6.3" "p.b6.4"
# [7,] "p.b7.1" "p.b7.2" "p.b7.3" "p.b7.4"
```

This works even if `m` was a vector since in R, a matrix is a vector with dimensions.

To fill in the matrix column-wise, its enough to give `m` the dimensions:

```
dim(m) <- c(7,4)
```